# showModelDialog and javascript debugging

Tags: visual-studio-2012

We are using windows 8 and vs2012. In our application we use showModelDialog at lots of places. When we debug on main window, js debugging works fine, but if we add any breakpoint on javascript related to the model dialog web page opened by showModeldialog causes following error -

No Source Available -

The current thread is not currently running code or the call stack could not be obtained.

Step to continue running and have the debugger stop the next time this thread runs code.

Step.

Thanks,

Daljit

Answer (score 0):

I had the similar error with Windows8 + IE10 + VS2012, but today I was update vs2012 with Update 2 and the problem is solved.

[VS2012 Update 2 here](http://www.microsoft.com/visualstudio/esn/downloads#d-visual-studio-2012-update)